# Getting the name of a hyperlink when it's clicked using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Is there a way to get the hyperlink name when you click on it using jQuery? I have the following code, I need some jQuery direction:

```
<a href="#" id="imageClick" name='<%# Eval("fileName1") %>'><asp:Image ID="myImage" name='<%# Eval("fileName1") %>' runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/Image/" + Eval("fileName") %>'  /></a>
```

Basically I would like to return the value of whatever **<%# Eval("fileName1") %>** is.

Thanks.

EDIT: To be more clear, I have a popup page which contains a listView which that has images and radio buttons. The requirement is if you click on the radio button, it should get the value of that specific choice and close the popup. I'm also passing a value back to the parent window. So this is what I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#form1").change(function () {

        var val = "";

        if ($('input:radio[name=myRadio]:checked').val()) {
            val = $('input:radio[name=myRadio]:checked').val();
        }

        if (val != "") {

            $(window.opener.document).find('#txtLogos').val(val);
            // Close the window
            window.close();
        }
    });
});
```

This works fine when I click on one of the radio buttons. But now they added another requirement that if they click on the images they want the same result (Obviously without disrupting the functionality that the radio button has).

Comment: Ok so on form change you need to figure out which image was clicked on right?

Comment: You have only one image?

Comment: No I have thousands. I'm loading a listView dynamically using the image names as shown in my question.

Comment: SO yuo want to know which all images have been clicked on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just access it using `this.name` inside your click handler. `this` here is the Dom element (Don't need jquery to retrieve the element attribute value), so just directly access the name attribute of the element.

```
$('#imageClick').click(function(){
   alert(this.name);
});
```

#### Edit

Form change will not be triggered if you click on an image; unlike input, select, textarea etc. So you need to trigger form change manually on image click event (to simulate a radio button click triggering the form change event).

Bind a click handler to your images to add class:

```
$('yourimageselector').click(function(){

      $(this).toggleClass('checkedImage'); // Add a class on first click and again clicked on it remove the class to say it is turned off. If you dont want a turn off functionality simply say :

     //$(this).addClass('checkedImage'); //or if this is the only class then this.className = 'checkedImage' classList is not yet supported in all browsers.

     $('yourform').change(); //as this is image it wont trigger form change event so you need to manually trigger form's change event (only for input, select, textarea etc form change will be triggered).       

});
```

And in your form event:

```
$("#form1").change(function () {

        var imgNames= $('.checkedImage')
              .map(function(){return this.name; })
              .get(); // Will get you all the image names in an array.
   //if it is just one image then simply do if($('.checkedImage').length > 0) $('.checkedImage')[0].name, 

   //Code follows

  });
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrHGD/)

Comment: Half jQuery and Half JavaScript! What sorcery is that? :)

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui You need to figure out when you use jquery and when not to... That will answer your question.

Comment: But if you are including jQuery then make it a pure jQuery approach! :) OP wants it to be jQuery as well! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had actually thought of working around this as I am handling a few button clicks in my application. But in this specific case, I'm also checking for a form change action. Is there a way to put this within an if statement?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Its the same comment as above. When you can just access something directly why you want to go using a wrapper? i dont understand. i see it stupidity to do $(this).attr('name') when this.name gives you what you want.

Comment: @user2471103 I didn't clearly understand, you want to put whcih part in if statement.

Comment: @Moh: Using jQuery merely for the sake of using jQuery isn't smart. It should be used when it actually provides benefit, and should be avoided when it only adds overhead with no benefit.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui also don't think that jquery does something out of the box to figure out element name than accessing it with native javascript DOM operation :). have a look at the jquery source code at times apart from just using it blindly.

Comment: Thanks for this PSL, the issue is this would disrupt the radio buttons I have which are supposed to have the same functionality as the image click?

Comment: @user2471103 i dont understand your complete structure, what disrupt means but this answer is a pointer. I think you can take it forward from here. Also sine this is an answer to your orig question do remember to mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

this can also work in the event handler of your click :

```
document.getElementById("new-answer-activity").name
```

Comment: OP needs a jQuery approach! :)